# Resize Tkinter Window FROM THE RIGHT (python)

Tags: python, resize, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm not sure on how to articulate this...

I have a Tkinter window, and I need to hide half of this window when a button is pressed. 
However, I need the left-most side to be hidden, so that the window is now half the size it originally was,
and shows the right half of the original window.

All of Tkinter's resize functions span from the *left* side of the window. 
Changing the geometry values can only show the *left* side whilst hiding the right; 
I need the inverse.

Does anybody know how to go about doing this?

(I don't want the user to have to drag the window border, 
I need the button to automate it).

---

Specs:

- Python 2.7.1
- Tkinter
- Windows 7

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to resize a window, or is the problem that you want to hide the widgets that are on the left side of the window (thus causing the window to shrink)? Do you need to hide whole widgets, or just part of some widgets?

Comment: I guess I aesthetically intend to hide half the widgets and shrink the window, but I didn't intend in such a method (as I have a lot of widgets).  

I was really just hoping for a conveniant method for right anchored resizing, but it looks as if there is no simple solution (which I find really strange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this do what you want ?

```
import Tkinter as Tk #tkinter

def toggle():
    if frame1.winfo_ismapped():
        frame1.grid_remove()
    else:
        frame1.grid()

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('-450+250')
frame1 = Tk.Frame(root, width=200, height=100, bg='red')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2 = Tk.Frame(root, width=200, height=100, bg='blue')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
Tk.Button(root, text='toggle', command=toggle).grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes actually, I think it would!  
There are a few small issues that arise because of the format of widgets, but I think this is a feasible solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use right-anchored geometry specifications by using a minus sign in the right place:

```
123x467-78+9
```

However, I don't know if this will work on Windows (the above is an X11 trick, and I don't know if it is implemented in the platform-compatibility layer or not); you might have to just calculate the new position given the projected size of the left side and use that.

Comment: Sadly, it looks as if you can only use the minus for the window position, not it's size. (Trying to do root.geometry('-800x800') gives error: 'Bad Geometry Specifier'.)

Comment: @Anti: A negative width (or height) makes no sense, given that I'm not a practicing Pure Mathematician.

Comment: I thought something similiar.  
How then can I resize a window using anchoring at all?
:(

Comment: Partial geometry specifiers (`WIDTHxHEIGHT`) work, but I forget whether they work with right-relative (or bottom-relative) positioning, especially on non-X11.

Answer (score 0):

My IT teacher had a suggestion:

Add a Scrollbar out of sight,
and after resizing the root window,
force the scrollbar to scroll all the way to the right.

(So I guess I'd have to create a canvas,
pack all my widgets to the frame,
pack the frame to the canvas,
configure the canvas with the scrollbar?)

I'm not sure if there's a function to set the current position of the scrollbar (thus xview of the window),
but I'd imagine there is.

Have yet to implement this, but it looks promising.

Thanks for the suggestions!